# Copy data from one worksheet to all other worksheets in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a data in `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH17:AO25")`.

I need to copy this data (formula) to all other sheets **(Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, ...)** to this same range `Range.("AH17:AO25")` in this workbook.

```
Public Sub Copy_Data()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("AH17").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-27]/1000"
Range("AH17").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AH17:AO25").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AH17:AO25").CopyDestination:_
  =wsheet.Ranges("AH17:AO25")

End Sub
```

Comment: Solve what though?  Are you having a problem with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Public Sub Copy_Data_Bis()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, Sh1 As Worksheet
   Set Sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Sh1.Range("AH17:AO25").Formula = "=RC[-27]/1000"
   For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If sh.Name <> Sh1.Name Then
        sh.Range("AH17:AO25").Formula = Sh1.Range("AH17:AO25").Formula
     End If
   Next
End Sub
```

The code does not need any selection, copy - paste and it should be very fast...